# Wifi REST API GET call - how to concatenate and pass URL parameters?

Tags: api, rest, arduino, wifi, arduino-uno

I'm not too familiar with the arduino c+ language, but I would like to get this native code to work.

In curl this works:
curl "http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetTextSentiment?text=i+feel+great&outputMode=json&apikey=my-apikey"^C

So I am trying to use a WiFi client for the same request but it seems the passing and parsing of the URL parameters is causing a problem.

sprintf(request,"/calls/text/TextGetTextSentiment?apikey=%s&text=%s&outputMode=%s","31adba6dfc3a879b88762f50efc9f892bd573207", "i+feel+great", "json");
Serial.println(request);

When I print the request, everything after the & gets truncated.

char serverName[] = "access.alchemyapi.com";
if(client.connect(serverName,port) == 1)
{
sprintf(outBuf,"GET %s HTTP/1.1",page);
client.println(outBuf);
sprintf(outBuf,"Host: %s",serverName);
client.println(outBuf);
client.println(F("Connection: close\r\n"));
}

This works (HTTP status 200, though with missing parameters error from the API service) if I only pass in 1 parameter.